# Show two complex functions are conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on a homework problem that asks

> Show that the functions $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^2 + 1}$ and $g(z) = z^2 + 1$ are conjugate.

Two functions $f$ and $g$ are conjugate if there is a conformal map $\varphi$ such that $f \circ \varphi = \varphi \circ g$.  So I am looking for a function $\varphi$ that satisfies
$$ \frac{\varphi(z)^2}{\varphi(z)^2 + 1} = \varphi(z^2 + 1). $$
I know that fixed points and critical points are conjugate invariants, so that gives $\varphi(0) = 0$ (because $g'(z) = 0$ iff $z = 0$), but that isn't helping me any.  Ideas or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try $\displaystyle{\varphi(z)=\frac{1}{z}}$.

Comment: @LeoTheKub Thank you.  If you like, you can post that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish. Try $${\varphi(z)=\frac{1}{z}}.$$